# How to solve SOAP Error 500 in android

Tags: android, soap, wsdl

How to findout SOAP_NAMESPACE, SOAP_ACTION, SOAP_METHOD_NAME in wsdl web service for android

my webservice is below:

http://demo.ecount.in/eService.svc?wsdl

Please Help me if anyone knows.

Thank You.

My Code is Below:

```
public final static String URL = "http://demo.ecount.in/eService.svc?wsdl";
public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public static final String SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX = "urn:eService/ExcuteDataSet1";
private static final String METHOD = "ExcuteDataSet1";

private String resp;

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
            //bodyOut is the body object to be sent out with this envelope
            envelope.bodyOut = request;
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + METHOD, envelope);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error XmlPullParserException", e.toString());
            }
            //bodyIn is the body object received with this envelope
            if (envelope.bodyIn != null) {
                //getProperty() Returns a specific property at a certain index.
                SoapPrimitive resultSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn)
                        .getProperty(0);
                resp=resultSOAP.toString();
            }
```

it Gives Error: "HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500"

Answer (score 1):

Please check below snapshot for SOAP_NAMESPACE, SOAP_ACTION, SOAP_METHOD_NAME

[image]

Comment: ya i check that but this webservice is different than my webservice please check my webservice

Comment: Okay let me know is this helpful for you or not.

Comment: 500 error code means Internal Server Error, that doesn't mean request is invalid. might be some other issue at server end.